# JAXB serialize JsonElement field in POJO

Tags: java, json, serialization, jaxb, jackson

I have a POJO class like:

```
class Cat {
  public Cat() {}
  private String name;
  private JsonElement arbitraryProperties;
}
```

I am using Jackson (JAXB) and `cat` is a resource I want to import and export.

```
GET /cats/{id}
POST /cats
```

Export is working fine. Import did not work because `JsonElement` is abstract. So I added @JsonDeserialize(using = MyJsonElementDeserialize.class) annotation to the `arbitraryProperties field`.

The `MyJsonElementDeserialize` class looks like:

```
public class JsonElementDeserialize extends JsonDeserializer<JsonElement> {

public JsonElementDeserialize() {
}

@Override
public JsonElement deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    return new JsonObject(); // here I need to create my object later
}
```

}

When I now call POST /cats with payload:

```
{
  "name": "Mia",
  "arbitraryProperties": {
        "a": 3,
        "b": [],
        "c": {
            "d": "race"
        }
   }
 }
```

Jacksons returns error code 400:

> Unrecognized field "a" (class Cat), not marked as ignorable (1 known properties: "name"]).

Where is my mistake? How can I have a `JsonElement` in my POJO that gets automatically serialized and deserialized?

Comment: what is `JsonElement` ? is it part of GSON? so why not use it?

Comment: Yes JsonElement is a abstract class from GSON. https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html

Comment: One minor suggestion: title says "serialization", but question is about "deserialization". It would make sense to change title, easier to find relevant questions that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using a setter method in `Cat` to transform something Jackson parses (e.g. `Map<String, Object>`) to a GSON `JsonElement` type:

```
void setArbitraryProperties(Map<String, Object> properties) {
    arbitraryProperties = new Gson().toJsonTree(properties).getAsJsonObject();
}
```

You can do something similar inside a custom deserializer if you can't use a setter here. I find setters/getters simpler for transformations with Jackson.

Note that a `Gson` instance is employed to convert the `Map` to `JsonElement` (a `JsonObject` actually). Docs for [toJsonTree](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJsonTree-java.lang.Object-).

Since you have a field of a type defined in GSON and therefore you have  GSON as a dependency and inexorably need GSON to create this field, you may consider Sharon's suggestion and skip Jackson and use GSON for deserialization.

Comment: I think it's the best way to deal with unrecognized fields. Or even better to use Map as a type of field instead of JsonElement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that deserializers must consume all content that they cover: that is, if your deserializer does not "read" JSON content that would bind (contents of `a` here), they are left for further processing.

Solution should be easy, just call

```
jsonParser.skipChildren();
```

in `deserialize` method and it will skip over current input token, as well as all of its contents (if its JSON Object or Array).

Alternatively, if you wanted to use contents, you could use

```
jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
```

and there are a few other convenience methods.

Answer (score 1):

If could, I would change JsonElement to  JsonNode, and use “Tree Model” of Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE" and @ResponseBody in controller method if you are using Spring mvc.